# Web scraping ticketing information using Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I've the task of web scraping ticketing information from a travel booking site (http://english.ctrip.com/trains/#ctm_ref=nb_tn_top).

I have piecemealed some code to get to the point of opening the target URL and searching for defined parameters. I am now stuck on parsing information.

Within the HTML (provided below), I am looking to parse the class-type, data-trainnumber, and seat-left classes. So for example, I would want to retrieve "2nd class seat", "G102", and "416" from the first instance.

I am having trouble identifying the correct "class" to use and which functions can be leveraged to target the specific values.

The minimal code that I have thus far:

```
    With oIE
    .navigate sURL
    .Visible = True

    Do Until (.readyState = 4 And Not .Busy)
       DoEvents
    Loop

    ' search for particular entry

    Set ElementCol = .document.getElementsByTagName("button")
        For Each btnInput In ElementCol
            If btnInput.innerText = "Search" Then
                btnInput.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next btnInput

     ' ensure page has been fully loaded
    Do Until (.readyState = 4 And Not .Busy)
       DoEvents
    Loop

End With

Set ieDoc = oIE.document
Set ElementCol = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("train-seat")
    For Each optInput In ElementCol
        MsgBox optInput.innerHTML
    Next optInput
```

**HTML of source**:

```
            <ul class="train-seat">
                    <li class=" ">
                        <span class="class-type">2nd class seat</span><span class="c-price"><span class="price-currency">CNY</span>&nbsp;<em class="price-num">553</em><span class="seat-left">416 left</span></span><a class="c-btn btn-key" href="javascript:;" 
                           data-trainnumber="G102" 
                           data-departtime="06:43" 
                           data-departdate="1449187200" 
                           data-departstation="Rochester" 
                           data-arrivalstation="Albany" 
                           data-seatname="2nd class">Book</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=" ">
                        <span class="class-type">1st class seat</span><span class="c-price"><span class="price-currency">CNY</span>&nbsp;<em class="price-num">933</em><span class="seat-left">66 left</span></span><a class="c-btn btn-key" href="javascript:;" 
                           data-trainnumber="G102" 
                           data-departtime="06:43" 
                           data-departdate="1449187200" 
                           data-departstation="Rochester" 
                           data-arrivalstation="Albany" 
                           data-seatname="1st class">Book</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=" ">
                        <span class="class-type">Business class seat</span><span class="c-price"><span class="price-currency">CNY</span>&nbsp;<em class="price-num">1,748</em><span class="seat-left">19 left</span></span><a class="c-btn btn-key" href="javascript:;" 
                           data-trainnumber="G102" 
                           data-departtime="06:43" 
                           data-departdate="1449187200" 
                           data-departstation="Rochester" 
                           data-arrivalstation="Albany" 
                           data-seatname="Business">Book</a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you are working with now? What doesn't it do that you want it to? Reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may help you get more out of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to isolate the elements as you discover them and then only deal with the items within each matching element in turn. There are many ways to do this. For me, I've found that dealing with the **collection** of items returned by [getElementsByClassName method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975198(v=vs.85).aspx) or [getElementsByTagName method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536439(v=vs.85).aspx) can best be handled using [With ... End With statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). This isolates the item so that subsequent calls for internal items only discover the matches within the parent element.

```
With oie
    .navigate "http://english.ctrip.com/trains/List/Index?DepartureCity=shanghai%28%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7%29&ArrivalCity=beijing%28%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC%29&DepartDate=12-7-2015&TrainNo=&DepartureCityPinyin=&ArrivalCityPinyin=&DepartureStation=%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7&ArrivalStation=%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC&searchboxArg="
    .Visible = True

    Do Until (.readyState = 4 And Not .Busy)
       DoEvents
    Loop

    With oie.document
        For ts = 0 To .getelementsbyclassname("train-seat").Length - 1
            'work with each UL of class 'train-seat'
            With .getelementsbyclassname("train-seat")(ts)
                'work with each LI within the UL
                For li = 0 To .getelementsbytagname("li").Length - 1
                    With .getelementsbytagname("li")(li)
                        'only keep working if there is at least one class-type class and one anchor element
                        If CBool(.getelementsbyclassname("class-type").Length) And _
                           CBool(.getelementsbyclassname("price-num").Length) And _
                           CBool(.getelementsbytagname("a").Length) Then
                            'show first 'class-type' class within the LI
                            Debug.Print .getelementsbyclassname("class-type")(0).innertext
                            'show first 'price-num' class within the LI
                            Debug.Print .getelementsbyclassname("price-num")(0).innertext
                            'the other one are trickier; get the first A element
                            With .getelementsbytagname("a")(0)  'c-btn btn-key class
                                'but can be parsed using Split of the outerHTML on the quote character
                                vPIECEs = Split(.outerhtml, Chr(34))
                                Debug.Print vPIECEs(13) '& vPIECEs(14) '& vPIECEs(7)
                            End With
                        End If
                    End With
                Next li
            End With
        Next ts

    End With
End With

Set oie = Nothing
```

I've chosen to use `Debug.Print` to send the output to the VBE's Immediate window (Ctrl+G) rather than repeatedly show MsgBox popups.

Comment: Jeeped - I really appreciate your help on this. Just for the sake of learning, may I ask what the (ts) does within the following line of code?

.getelementsbyclassname("train-seat")(ts)

Comment: That's seems like too much to deal with in comments. Suggest you start a new question with updated code and relevant details.